# Sed command in Windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, sed, cmd

I need to get absolute path of existing directory and change one of it's property.
I wrote simple script for this task and everything works great on my linux machine.

```
SET "IGNITE_PATH=%cd%\standalone\configuration\ignite.xml"
sed -i -r "s#(core@node\/scripts-dir-path=).*#\1%SCRIPTS_PATH%#g" .\standalone\configuration\platform-config.properties
```

Resul of this script looks like:

```
core@node/ignite-config-path=/c/../standalone/configuration/ignite.xml
```

Then i adapted this script for Windows users.

```
SET "IGNITE_PATH=%cd%\standalone\configuration\ignite.xml"
sed -i -r "s#(core@node\/ignite-config-path=).*#\1%IGNITE_PATH%#g" .\standalone\configuration\platform-config.properties
```

But faced with problem. The result of Windows bat script looks like:

```
core@node/ignite-config-path=C:DESKTOP...STANDALONENFIGURATIONIGNITE.XML
```

All path presents in Caps lock as single word and some of words look like stucked together.

Is this behaviour because of different separators on unix and Windows? What will be solution in this case?

Comment: Try escaping the backslashes in your SET "IGNORE_PATH...

Comment: I don't know what `sed` actually expects, but perhaps it wants the forward-slash `/` as path separator; if so, do `SET "IGNITE_PATH=%IGNITE_PATH:\=/%"` after your `SET` command line...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks man! it works great.

Comment: Why is this tagged bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the tool `sed` but I assume it expects the forward-slash `/` to be the path separator as it comes from Unix systems.
The Windows command interpreter (`cmd`) however uses the backslash `\` as the path separator.
Therefore I suggest to insert the following line immediately after your `SET` command line:

```cmd
SET "IGNITE_PATH=%IGNITE_PATH:\=/%"
```

This uses the [sub-string replacement syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) to replace every `\` by a `/`.